# JQMobile .trigger('create') not working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm having a strange problem with the .trigger('create') method in a jqmobile app.

I'm trying to create some shared, re-used pages accross the site.

Here is my index.html;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>phonegap & jquery mobile boilerplate</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.theme.css"/>
    <script>
        var userAgent = navigator.userAgent + '';
        if (userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') > -1) {
            document.write('<script src="js/lib/cordova-iphone.js"></sc' + 'ript>');
            var mobile_system = 'iphone';
        } else if (userAgent.indexOf('Android') > -1) {
            document.write('<script src="js/lib/cordova-android.js"></sc' + 'ript>');
            var mobile_system = 'android';
        } else {
            var mobile_system = '';
        }
    </script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- your scripts here -->
    <script src="js/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/globals.js"></script>
    <script src="js/logged_in.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="headerDiv" data-role='header'><a href="index.html" data-icon="home">Home</a>

        <h1>Jubilee Distributors</h1>
        <a href="login.html" id="logged_in" data-icon="home">Login</a></div>
    <div id="navDiv"></div>
    <div data-role="content">Blah Blah
    </div>

    <div id='footerDiv' data-role="footer"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my shared nav.html:

```
<div data-role='navbar'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="orders.html">Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="clients.html">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On dom ready i'm executing the following in the globals.js file:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});

$(function () {
    $('#navDiv').load('shared/nav.html').trigger('create');
    $('#footerDiv').load('shared/footer.html').trigger("create");
});
```

The html loads into the div no probs, but the trigger doesn't seem to be doing anything as in styling it.. Is there something I'm missing?

Cheers,

Comment: what is the 'create' event? is some custom event made by you?

Comment: 'create' is the event in which jQMobile enhances the markup loaded in the DOM...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, if it doesn't work we'll try something else:

Put globals.js BEFORE you Jquery mobile like this:

```
   <script src="js/globals.js"></script>
   <script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
   <script src="js/logged_in.js"></script>
```

if that doesn't work, rewrite your last function this way:

```
$(function () {
    $('#navDiv').load('shared/nav.html', function(){$(this).trigger('create')});
    $('#footerDiv').load('shared/footer.html', function(){$(this).trigger('create')});
});
```

That way it waits until your files are fully loaded and inserted into the DOM before jQM enhances;

Comment: Great, which one? I suspect if you do the first, you won't even need to add the trigger('create') because the content will be in the DOM before any 'pageinit' is fired